# How to speak about future unreal conditional statement?

Tags: future-tense, conditional-constructions

How can I speak suppose I want to ask a gentleman, "If there had a dress code tomorrow, it would be better". Is this the right way to talk about the future possibility?

Comment: habbu, since I'm an incompetent speaker I cannot help you, but are you sure "If there had" is grammatical? Or  should it be "If there were", perhaps?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! The expression you want is *If there **were***: the dummy subject *there* is used only with *BE*. I see that you have also posted this question on [elu.se]. Such cross-posting between StackExchange sites is frowned on; I suggest you delete the question at one site.

Comment: @Carlo_R *Incompetent*? For shame! "Less than perfectly competent" is not "incompetent"; you are more competent than many of the native speakers I work with every day. :)

Comment: @Stoney, hearing these things from you make me really happy, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

OP's proposed utterance...

> 1: If there had a dress code tomorrow, it would be better.

...is completely ungrammatical, and wouldn't be produced by any native speaker. The nearest equivalent that *could* be produced is...

> 2: ?If there had **been** a dress code tomorrow, it would be better. *(? = "suspect phrasing")*

...but many native speakers wouldn't say that either, because it mixes verb forms. They'd probably say...

> 3: If there had **been** a dress code tomorrow, it would **have been** be better.
>    *or...*
>    4: ?If there **was** a dress code tomorrow, it would be better. *(also suspect phrasing, but often occurs)*
>    *or (a bit "over-precise", but grammatically consistent)*...
>    5: If there **were to be** a dress code tomorrow, it would be better.
>    *or (agonisingly over-precise, to my ear, but also grammatical)*...
>    6: If there **were** a dress code tomorrow, it would be better.

The important thing to notice is that although it's a ***future*** "unreal" condition, all acceptable variations above use what appear to be ***past*** tense verb forms.

No valid constructions use future tense for the "unreal future" (so *If there **will be** a dress code...* is never valid). Note that #2 and #3 above both strongly imply that there definitely *won't* be a dress code, whereas #4 and #5 leave that possibility open (but they normally imply the speaker thinks there won't be).

---

Finally, it's also worth pointing out the possibility of...

> 7: If there **is** a dress code tomorrow, it **will be** be better.

...which I don't think counts as ***unreal*** future. It's an ***unknown*** future possibility, in which context it's perfectly okay to use present tense because it's unknown ***at the time of speaking*** (but it would be at least "highly unusual" in most contexts to continue using the present tense with *"...it **is** better"*).

Comment: "If there had been a dress code tomorrow"??? Can people actually say that in England? It sounds terrible to my American ear.

Comment: @Peter: I don't see anything wrong with [If you had come tomorrow...](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22if+you+had+come+tomorrow%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), or [If it had been tomorrow...](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22if+it+had+been+tomorrow%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example. Sure - they look a little odd out of context, but in appropriate contexts I think these are perfectly ordinary constructions. I'd be boggled if it turned out only the English use them.

Comment: But both of those mean "if you had come tomorrow [instead of today]", and not "if there had been a dress code tomorrow [instead of there not being one]". I find the first construction grammatical, and the second one incorrect. So for the first meaning, your sentence would be fine; but the first meaning seems so unlikely that I didn't even consider it.

Comment: @Peter: That seems such a fine distinction I can't really see that ordinary speakers would habitually be capable of recognising and observing it as making any given usage either "grammatical" or not. Also don't forget we don't know OP's full context - the speaker and addressee might both know perfectly well that there's only a dress code on one day within, say, a week-long art exhibition. And it turns out it's *today*, but since they're wearing t-shirts today, they can't go in.

Comment: I would think this distinction is a natural grammatical one to Americans; it certainly is completely natural to me. And some very complicated grammatical distinctions are used habitually by ordinary speakers. For example, when to use which article in English (which many ESL students get wrong); it's much more complicated than this distinction.

Comment: @Peter: In all seriousness, you're almost certainly much cleverer than me (which is to say much, *much* cleverer than the average Anglophone! :). What seems easy and natural to you (but somewhat "fine" to me) probably isn't so obvious to everyone else. But I do think there's a tendency for "educated" Americans to pay more attention to grammar/logic in their choice of phrasing, compared to British counterparts. Which I put down to the greater importance of language as a "cultural unifier" in America, where so many are non-native speakers of the national language.

Comment: To throw another American hat into the ring, I have to agree with @Peter on this one (though the rest of the answer sounds great to me; +1). I don't exactly know how to articulate *why* it sounds wrong, but since tomorrow hasn't happened yet... Hmm. I don't know how to explain it but I definitely would pause if I heard it used in conversation. Just my two cents! And I must say, as I tend to agree with you most of the time, this is very odd for me ;)

Comment: @Wendikidd: I don't even have a problem with [If you had have been there](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22if+you+had+have+been+there%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which John Lawler implies is grammatically nonsensical (he says it [makes his teeth itch](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/62490/2637)). It's an ***unreal** future* that's already known ***not*** to be going to happen, so I'm quite happy to use past perfect. That's even further away from *real, present* than simple past (which per my answer, works when it isn't *certain* whether the condition will in fact apply).

Answer (score 0):

I would say, "It would be better if there WERE a dress code."